# div shifting when user resize the window

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
the pic shows up the footer shifting when user resize the window[1]
```

here is about `footer-row` in css setting

```
#footer-row {
   text-align: center;
   color: white;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 9pt;
   position: absolute;
   bottom:0;
}
```

and the whole container's setting

```
.container-fluid {
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   /*position:relative;*/
}
```

sorry to everyone... I modify my question...
my question is ... how can I make the all divs fixed no matter what user resize the window?

Comment: where is the jQuery? Have you tried with `position:fixed;` ?

Comment: sorry... my fault... i don't have enough reputation to upload the image.

Comment: Hi Learner.. i can give you the website, if you want. coz too much code

Answer (score 0):

Using this HTML:

```
<div id="myElement" style="position: absolute">This stays at the top</div>
```

This is the javascript you want to use. It attaches an event to the window's scroll and moves the element down as far as you've scrolled.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#myElement').css('bottom', -1*$(this).scrollTop() + "px");
});
```

check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/fZc2L/